# Using FARGATE task to provision RDS once

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-fargate

In my current setup I use cloudformation to setup an RDS instance. After this I would like to populate this database by running an SQL script (the DB = postgres 11.5).

I created an image for this and am able to successfully make the task defition and cluster. I would like to make sure that this image runs once and only once. I can of course schedule it for an exact time in the future but there has to be a better way.

I only found the options for scheduling (using Rules) or using a service (which AWS ensures will keep running), neither of which are what I like to achieve.

In short: How do I make sure my FARGATE task runs once from a cloudformation script?

[EDIT]
I tried to use an AWS::Events::Rule using ScheduleExpression: 'rate(2000 days)' but the first iteration does not run. Getting a bit frustrating now.

Comment: No one? I tried to use a "AWS::Events::Rule" for this but to no avail.

Comment: Meanwhile I'm still puzzling on. Current checking out SNS and Lambda to get to my goal. Still any hint will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t know what fargate is but if you create an aws::customresource it will run only once if you don’t change any of its properties

Comment: Thnx for your answer. Fargate is the engine to run Docker containers. I will check the customresources.